# How do install Ubuntu on a netbook with a 32-bit atom processor?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, dell

I'm trying to install Ubuntu onto an old Dell Inspiron Mini 10, which still has its "Designed for Microsoft Windows XP" sticker on the front. :)

The trouble is the normal installer isn't working at all. I've been trying the 32-bit version of Ubuntu 12.04.5 Desktop on a USB flash drive, because I found something somewhere that said 12.04 was supposed to be compatible with the Inspiron mini 10.

After choosing "Install" from the boot options, I see the Ubuntu logo with the "loading dots" for a minute or so, but then without fail it switches to a big error message that reads:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: run-init Tainted: G S 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu
Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 1011/CN0G45, BIOS A06 07/29/2009
 00000000 00000000 f5895ef0 c1680147 f5898000 f5895f14 c167569a c1870694
 c1af4c20 f5895f30 00000246 f5898000 c197bfc0 f5898000 f5895f34 c105a786
 c18708bc 00000100 f5898000 f5898284 f5898000 00000001 f5895f64 c105bc44
Call Trace:
 [<c1680147>] dump_stack+0x41/0x52
 [<c167569a>] panic+0x87/0x18f
 [<c105a786>] find_new_reaper+0x46/0x100
 [<c105bc44>] forget_original_parent+0x34/0x170
 [<c1121120>] ? perf_cgroup_switch+0x1a0/0x1a0
 [<c105bd93>] exit_notify+0x13/0xf0
 [<c105c3ba>] do_exit+0x1aa/0x3e0
 [<c1184ef7>] ? SyS_writer+0x57/0xa0
 [<c105c628>] SyS_exit+0x18/0x20
 [<c168b377>] syscall_call+0x7/0xb
drm_kms_helper: panic occurred, switching back to text console
```

I also read something online that suggested pressing "Tab" on the boot options and then manually adding `forcepae --forcepae` to the command. So I tried that, but that didn't change anything; it still encounters the same error message.

Help! I'd really like to get Linux running on this netbook.

Comment: have you tried xubuntu or lubuntu? http://xubuntu.org/  and http://lubuntu.net/

Comment: Yes, I have tried both. In both cases I see very similar results: I see the loading page for some seconds, but then the screen just goes black.

Comment: Will the live USB run?

Comment: @OrganicMarble no unfortunately it won't; the same kernel panic error occurs when I try to just run it.

Comment: Hmm, that is a good clue that it won't work without some tweaking.  If I were you, I'd work on getting the live USB to run before I considered actually installing.  Starting with lemonsqueeze's suggestions.  And I'd work on Lubuntu.  Ubuntu 12.04 has OK performance on my netbook but I have to use the 2d desktop, which isn't supported in later versions.

Answer (score 3):

First thing I would try is to boot the live CD with `acpi=off`, `noapic` and/or `nolapic` boot options, they can help with a good many hardware related kernel panics situations.

You should be able to set these with <kbd>F6</kbd>
From [Ubuntu LiveCD documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD.27s_Default_Boot_Options) :

> F6. Other Options. ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) and EDD (Enhanced Disk Drive) options which may help if your computer does not support or has problems with these systems. Highlight the selection and press the ENTER key or SPACE key to select it. An "X" will appear, indicating selection. Multiple items can be selected from this popup menu. Hit ESC to leave the popup menu. The selections are retained at the time the user presses the ESC key.

[image: boot menu]

Note: You could install 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04 also, working fine with atom processor.

Comment: Yesterday I tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 (i386) with all three of those options disabled (acpi=off, noapic, nolapic). Unfortunately, I ran into the same problem (kernal panic), only this time the graphics weren't as good leading up to that point.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you need to install lubuntu also using the `forcepae -- forcepae` kernel option.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE

or the fake-pae method

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu-fake-PAE

and it's possible your processor is completely not pae capable. If this is the case, you will need to follow the instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/9w

---

Explaination:

The kernel panic indicates tainted kernel because of S which translates to using an SMP kernel with a processor that is not SMP capable. You may also get this error and a kernel panic when a processor actually is pae capable but does not communicate that capability properly.

---

Also, you may want to try the mini.iso installation method as you may not have enough RAM to run the normal install.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

and

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall

Installation is very straightforward; follow the on screen instructions. Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate the cursor, use the <kbd>space bar</kbd> to select or deselect an option and use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to proceed.

I recommend using 15.04 but if that doesn't work, try 12.04.

If installing using 12.04, I believe the system does an initial install and then reboots. After reboot, you will have to run the following command to proceed:

```
tasksel
```